# Cannot serve epub files in IIS6

Tags: iis, iis-6, http-status-code-404

i am trying to serve `epub` files in IIS6 (Windows Server 2003), but instead the browser serves a `404 Not Found` page.

How do i serve EPUB in IIS6?

---

1. Open the IIS Microsoft Management Console (MMC), right-click the local computer name, and then click **Properties**.
2. Click **MIME Types**.

   [image]
3. Click **New**.

   [image]
4. In the **Extension** box, type the file name extension that you want (**`.epub`**).

   [image]
5. In the **MIME Type** box, type **`application/epub+zip`**.

   [image]
6. And click **OK**:

   [image]
7. Apply the new settings. Note that you must restart the World Wide Web Publishing Service or wait for the worker process to recycle for the changes to take effect.

   [image]
8. Return to the **MIME Types** dialog, and confirm that your changes were not saved across IIS restart:

   [image]
9. Also confirm that IIS is still not able to serve `epub` files:

   [image]

How do i serve EPUB from IIS 6 (Windows Server 2003)?

### Bonus Reading

- [IIS 6.0 does not serve unknown MIME types](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326965)

Comment: Great reference!  Maybe move the "answer" section to an answer on the question, for clarify?

Comment: It should be a great reference. Most of it is copied from the [Microsoft KB article in question](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326965).

Comment: @ShaneMadden Ummm...it's not an answer - it was the stuff i tried that didn't work. Pay attention to **Step 8**, where the mime type does not save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Open IIS manager
2. Expand the server from the tree pane on left
3. Expand Web Sites
4. Right click on the web site that will be serving the epub files and select properties
5. Open the HTTP Header tab and then MIME types from the bottom of the pane.
6. Add the .epub extension with MIME type "application/epub+zip"

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the box "**Enable Direct Metabase Edit**" on the IIS properties page (above where the MIME type options are), before you add the new MIME type. The correct procedure is:

1. Ensure you understand backup/restore procedures for the IIS Metabase.xml (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324277). You need to be able to restore a functioning copy of the Metabase.xml file in case something goes wrong.
2. Open the IIS Microsoft Management Console (MMC), right-click the local computer name, and then click Properties.
3. Check the box next to "Enable Direct Metabase Edit". Right-click on All Tasks and Restart IIS.
4. Return to the IIS Properties page and Click MIME Types.
5. Click New.
6. In the Extension box, type the file name extension that you want (.epub).
7. In the MIME Type box, type application/epub+zip.
8. Click OK.

9.Apply the new settings. Note that you must restart the World Wide Web Publishing Service or wait for the worker process to recycle for the changes to take effect.

10.Return to the MIME Types dialog, and confirm that your changes were saved.

11.Download an .epub file natively via a browser and confirm the file handling is correct.